# Include multiple jquery countdowns inside HTML Table only sets one time

Tags: jquery, html-table, countdown

I am working on a project where I need to show the status of several auctions on one page. Each item has a different end date. I give each row a unique ID and then use that id to set the time, but it only set one time. 
This is my script code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){  
$('tr[id]').each(function () {
 var $this = $(this);
 var endDate = new Date();
 var count = $this.attr("id");
 var year = parseInt(count.slice(0,4));
 var month = parseInt(count.slice(4,6));
 var day = parseInt(count.slice(6,8));
 var hour = parseInt(count.slice(8,10));
 var minute = parseInt(count.slice(10,12));
 var second = parseInt(count.slice(12,14));
 endDate.setFullYear(year, month - 1, day);
    endDate.setHours(hour+1);
    endDate.setMinutes(minute);
    endDate.setSeconds(second);
 $('.countdown-styled').countdown({
      until: endDate,
      format: 'dHMS',
      render: function(data) {
        var el = $(this.el);
        el.empty()
          .append("<div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.days, 2) + " <span>days</span></div>")
          .append("<div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.hours, 2) + " <span>hrs</span></div>")
          .append("<div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.min, 2) + " <span>min</span></div>")
          .append("<div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.sec, 2) + " <span>sec</span></div>")
      }

    });
});
});
</script>
```

And this is the layout of my table:

```
<body>
<table id="timerTable">  
<tr id="20130425190000">
<div class="countdown-styled" style="width:200px;"></div>
</tr>
<tr id="20130416190000">
<div class="countdown-styled" style="width:200px;"></div>
</tr>
<tr id="20130424190000">
<div class="countdown-styled" style="width:200px;"></div>
</tr>
```

This code sets the same time for every countdown in the table to the same time. (i.e. 13
Days 3
Hours 58
Minutes 24
Seconds 9 ) Any Ideas?

EDIT: If the way to go is by using the ID, then it must be in this format. This is dynamically set from the server and is returned in this format. That's why I use `parseInt` and `slice` it the way I do. The format is: year/month/day/hour/minute/second (XXXXXXXXXXXXXX)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are looping twice, with both $('tr[id]') and $('.countdown-styled').

You need to only apply the countdown to one specific descendant:

```
$this.find('.countdown-styled').countdown
```

For the record, your html is also missing the cells (td elements), I assume this is just a copy mistake.

Comment: I tried this. I made the change, then the timers disappeared altogether. Did I do something else wrong? The above code is basically all that is on the test page. Do I need to add something else to it?

Comment: Did you double check your html? How about the td elements?

Comment: I have. I made these jsfiddles to show you what I mean. 1) this without $this.find  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/xcUSq/)  and 2) with: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/xcUSq/1/)

Comment: @DavidTansey You are a genius!!! That was it. I completely forgot about them. thanks so much! Christophe You really helped me out with the jquery. That is not my strong suit. That catch was brilliant.

Comment: I like being called a GENIUS but @Christophe has been trying to bring that to your attention.  ;)